# finding string has " | , characters with sed command

Tags: regex, sed, terminal

I have files in a folder which have a string pattern looks like this

```
some other strings , "last_fico_high|679", "last_fico_low|675", continues...
```

want to find and remove this expressions from my file

```
"last_fico_high|can_be_any_number",
```

**with its quotation mark, pipe and final comma**

I have tried online regex editors and they seem okay I can find the pattern using this expression

```
("last_fico_high\|\d{0,}",)
```

But when I tried the pattern with sed command

```
sed -i -- 's/"last_fico_high\|\d{0,}",//g' *
```

the best string I am able to do is

```
|679"
```

What am I missing, or what should the regex expression look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` should work for you:

```
s='some other strings , "last_fico_high|679", "last_fico_low|675", continues...'

sed 's/"last_fico_high|[0-9]*",//g' <<< "$s"

some other strings ,  "last_fico_low|675", continues...
```

In default BRE mode, there is no need to escape the pipe.

Comment: Thank you, that works! but have a question why don't  `\d{0,}` expression do the same thing as `[0-9]*` ? Is there a more than one regex rules?

Comment: Yes BRE doesn't allow `\d`. You could use `[0-9]\{0,\}` in `sed`